# Change Background of html label using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="lifecycleStage">
<div id="private2">
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePrivate" value="preliminary"         id="preliminary"/>      <label for="preliminary">Preliminary</label>
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePrivate" value="prelist"             id="prelist"/>          <label for="prelist">Prelist</label>            
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePrivate" value="retired"             id="retired"/>          <label for="retired">Retired</label> <br>           
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePrivate" value="internal product"    id="internalProduct"/>  <label for="internalProduct">Internal Product</label>   
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePrivate" value="reference nop"       id="referenceNOP"/>     <label for="referenceNOP">Reference NOP</label>     
</div>
<div id="public">
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePublic" value="listed"               id="listed"/>           <label for="listed">Listed  ................</label>             
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePublic" value="approaching op"       id="approachingOP"/>    <label for="approachingOP">Approaching OP</label>      
    <input type="radio" name="lifecyclePublic" value="no longer available"  id="noLongerAvailable"/><label for="noLongerAvailable">No Longer Available</label> 
</div>
```

What I would like is to change the background of the selected label to a different 'unique' color. Example when prelist is selected, it has a blue background, but when retired is selected it has a black background.

any tips and tricks, much appreciated!

Comment: Unless the colors are randomized, this can be done with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use jQuery? Simply use CSS:

```
label {
    background-color: #000;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uZSak/).

Comment: @cimmanon: thanks, but I'd already created my own; was just editing it in as you posted your comment. =)

Comment: Well that's sneaky of you because I was just finishing up my fiddle when you posted my answer for me!

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the quick response, this will work perfectly.

Comment: Then I'm glad to have been of some help. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('label').on('click',function() {
    $('label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hpU6k/